# This is about zuul and routing

Tags: java, netflix-zuul

This question is about zuul and routing. Now to get zuul routing is quite easy in your application.yml you have the following

```
routes:
    silver:
      path: "/silver/**"
      serviceId: "SILVER-MICO-SERVICE"
      stripPrefix: true
    gold:
      path: "/gold/**"
      serviceId: "GOLD-MICO-SERVICE"
      stripPrefix: false
```

So if your URL has silver in it, it will direct the silver micro service, if it has gold it directs to the gold micro service.

But I have  a 3rd service, that I want to call before I direct the to the silver or gold. so i want something like

```
routes:
    silver:
      path: "/silver/**"
      serviceId: "SILVER-MICO-SERVICE"
      stripPrefix: true
    gold:
      path: "/gold/**"
      serviceId: "GOLD-MICO-SERVICE"
      stripPrefix: false
   throttle
     path: "/throttle/**"
      serviceId: "THROTTLE-MICO-SERVICE"
      stripPrefix: false
```

And when say silver is called

I will have the following in my filter, I would have a throttleFilter which will call out to the throttle micro service.
But I have no idea how to code a zuul call in Java.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is the code to do what I want to do. The functionality I needed was supplied by the EurekaClient

```
zuul 
    throttling:
      path: "/throttling/**"
      serviceId: "SITE-THROTTLING"
      stripPrefix: false
```

And in the code I have

```
@Autowired
private EurekaClient eurekaClient;

private boolean checkThrottling(String url) {
        
        InstanceInfo service = eurekaClient
                  .getApplication("SITE-THROTTLING")
                  .getInstances()
                  .get(0);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(service.getHomePageUrl())
                .append("/throttling")
                .append("?paramUrl=")
                .append(url);
        return webSevice.sendPost(sb.toString());

public boolean sendPost(String url) {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
        Boolean flag = webClient.get()
                                       .uri(url)
                                       .retrieve()
                                       .bodyToMono(Boolean.class)
                                       .block();
        return flag;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to route to throttle micro service cause you can route to only one micro service. Instead you can write a pre filter and call throttle micro service.
Here is an example of how to write a pre filter

```
import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class SimplePreFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        //You can apply custom logic if required
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
        //TODO you can call throttle micro service here
        return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you, but I want to call it through a eureka server. I mean to add eureka, but you cant edit this. So its zuul  eureka  and the 3 services. so I agree I need to call via a prefilter but is there a way  can just give the service id. Or o I need to use webclient or a resttemplate build up the URL and call it that way. The problem is all the services are accessed via eureka , and I would like to access throttling via eureka.

Comment: It will definitely work with webclient or resttemplate but I am not sure about eureka

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it would be something like that. Eureka discovery service is up and running but I cant use it unless the path contains throttling, which it wont, it will be silver or gold.